# Is this set path-connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, connectedness, path-connected

Consider $\left\{(e^{-x}\cos x, e^{-x}\sin x)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x\geq 0 \right\} \cup \left\{(0,0) \right\}.$ I need to see if this set is path connected. My guess is it is not primarily Because of the point $(0,0)$. There needs to be a path from $(0,0)$ to any other point in the set. Since the other points are of the form $(e^{-\alpha}\cos \alpha, e^{-\alpha}\sin \alpha)$ for some $\alpha\geq 0,$ I must have that there is some $\alpha$ that will put the point $(e^{-\alpha}\cos \alpha, e^{-\alpha}\sin \alpha)$ arbitrarily close to $(0,0)$. Since, $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are never zero at the same time we need to send $\alpha$ to $\infty.$ What we seem to have is the closure of the set $$\left\{(e^{-x}\cos x, e^{-x}\sin x)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x\geq 0 \right\}.$$ Am I going in the right direction? How would I prove that there is no path from $(0,0)$ to any other point in $\left\{(e^{-x}\cos x, e^{-x}\sin x)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x\geq 0 \right\}$?

Comment: The very definition of the set tells you how to connect a point in the set of the form $e^{(-1+i)t}$ to $(0,0)$. Use the curve $s\mapsto e^{(-1+i)s}$ defined on $[t,+\infty]$. To get a curve with domain as in the usual definition compose with a homeomorphism between $[0,1]$ and $[t,+\infty]$.

Comment: I'd say you have the right idea.  A path from $(x,y)$ to $(0,0)$ is a function $\gamma:[0.1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\gamma(0)=(x,y), \gamma(1)=(0,0)$

Comment: @plop A homeomorphism between a compact space and a non-compact one?

Comment: @saulspatz You are assuming a topology on $[t,+\infty]$, which is not the one that is induced (pulled back) by the map to $\mathbb{R^2}$. Since the set in the question is compact, to is $[t,+\infty]$ in this topology.

Comment: @plop I'm talking about the topology of the real line.  I don't understand how you would add $\infty$.

Comment: @saulspatz I know you are assuming that, and what I told you is that that is the wrong assumption. In the comment above I already told you how to add $+\infty$. Another way to look at the same topology is the one-point compactification of $[t,+\infty)$.

Comment: @plop Perhaps you could show me the path you have in mind?

Comment: @saulspatz No, I am not interested in doing that work for you. If you have doubts ask a question in a separate post and perhaps someone can help you.

Comment: @plop Just answer this question.

Comment: @saulspatz Only by thinking it yourself, you will get to understand those things that you are having trouble understanding. Homework: Spot the homeomorphism between $[1,+\infty]]$ and $[0,1]$ in the answer below. Homework 2: Describe a basis of the topology on $[0,1]$ and what is the topology in $[1,+\infty]$.

Comment: @saulspatz Did you manage to figure it out, or do you still have difficulties understanding it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\gamma$ be the path
$$
\gamma(t) = \begin{cases} 
(0, 0) &\text{ if } t = 0 \\
(e^{-\frac 1 t}\cos(\frac 1 t), e^{-\frac 1 t}\sin(\frac 1 t)) & t \in (0, 1]
\end{cases}
$$
This is continuous. To show this, it's clear that $\gamma$ is continuous on $(0, 1]$ so we only need to consider $t = 0$. Note that
$$
|(e^{-\frac 1 t} \cos(\frac 1 t), e^{- \frac 1 t}\sin(\frac 1 t))| = e^{-\frac 1 t}
$$
And so $\gamma$ is continuous at 0 using the $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ definition of continuity.

As you say, the set is path connected if any two points can be connected by a path. It's clear that for all $x \geq 0$ we can connect $(e^{-1}\cos(1), e^{-1}\sin(1))$ to $(e^{-x}\cos(x), e^{-x}\sin(x))$, and so concatenation with $\gamma$ will give a path connecting $(0, 0)$ to any point. Hence the set is path connected.

Comment: Ahh yes. Very clever thank you. I suppose my intuition mislead me.